# Need help understanding Hilbert's Nullstellensatz (weak version)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The theorem is stated in my lecture notes as follows:

Every proper ideal $\mathcal{a}$ of $k[x_1 , \dots , x_n]$ admits a point in $V(\mathcal{a};l)$ over some algebraic field extension l/k. In particular, if $k$ is algebraically closed, then $l=k$.

I am having a hard time understanding this last part.

For example, let $k = \mathbb{C}$, let $S = \{ x^2 + 1 , x^2 - 1 \} \subset \mathbb{C}[x]$, and let $a_S$ be the ideal generated by $S$. In this case, $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, so the theorem says there should be a point in $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying both $x^2 + 1$ and $x^2 - 1$. However, these polynomials have no common roots.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: $a_S=(1)$ is not a proper ideal.

Comment: The ideal generated by $x^2+1$ and $x^2-1$ is not proper unless $\operatorname{char}k=2$, in which case $1$ is a common root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal $a_S$ contains $x^2+1$ and $x^2-1$, so it contains $1=\frac{1}{2}((x^2+1)-(x^2-1))$ and hence $a_S = \mathbb{C}[x]$ is not a *proper* ideal, so the theorem (as stated) doesn't apply.

In this case (where the ideal is the whole ring), points in $V(\mathbb{C}[x],\mathbb{C})$ are also solutions to the equation $1=0$ (by the above expression for $1$), so there are no points: $V(\mathbb{C}[x],\mathbb{C}) = \varnothing$.